# DateTime object in a specific format irrespective of the input

Tags: c#, datetime

I have a ASP.NET MVC app that provides the user to pick a date which is stored into the ViewModel.

This is the code that converts to date object:

```
viewModel.startDateAndTime = Convert.ToDateTime(buyToday.DealStartDateAndTime);
```

One of the developers has his system date time set to this format:

> 24-Feb-2014

On that system he's getting FormatException.
I would like to set the date time to use this format:

> mm/dd/yyyy

not matter what the setting is on any system..

Tried using this piece of code which does'nt work:

```
 string startDate = "24-Feb-2014";
 DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "mmddyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Any clues are appreciated.
Thanks & Regards.

Comment: How does the user "pick a date"? Does he just enter it into a text field? Or do you use some kind of date picking control?

Comment: @Heinzi using bootstrap

Comment: As far as I can see, there are many date picking controls for bootstrap. Which one are you using? (What I am aiming at: Check if that control provides access to the chosen date *in a well-defined, fixed format*, and then parse that format.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your input string does not match parsing pattern.

`"24-Feb-2014"` is much different then `mmddyyyy`, isn't it?

You can use `DateTime.Parse` with `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`:

```
string startDate = "24-Feb-2014";
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.Parse(startDate, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

otherwise, with `ParseExact` the input has to exactly match pattern, so you should pass `24022014` as input. But, just so you know, `mm` means *minutes*. For *month*, use `MM` :) So pattern should be `ddMMyyyy`. Check [Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) page on MSDN.

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
string startDate = "24-Feb-2014";
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "dd-MMM-yyyy",System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Answer (score 0):

`mm` returns The minute, from 00 through 59. So use `MM`
The month, from 01 through 12.

```
string startDate = "24-Feb-2014";
DateTime startDateTime = DateTime.ParseExact(startDate, "ddMMyyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

[Custom Date and Time Format Strings](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)